# nginx + php-fpm70 getting 502 bad gateway

Tags: php, nginx, magento

I'm Getting 502 bad gateway error in one of my magento2 site.

Here are my configuration files.

nginx.conf configuration file

```
    user  nginx;
worker_processes 4;
worker_rlimit_nofile 100000;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
        use epoll;
#        worker_connections 1024;
    worker_connections 10240;
        multi_accept on;
}

http {
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type  application/octet-stream;
        access_log off;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
        rewrite_log on;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log main buffer=32k flush=300;

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        autoindex off;
        server_tokens off;
        port_in_redirect off;

        open_file_cache max=10000 inactive=5m;
        open_file_cache_valid 2m;
        open_file_cache_min_uses 1;
        open_file_cache_errors on;

        types_hash_max_size 4096;

     client_header_buffer_size 16k;
     large_client_header_buffers 4 32k;

        fastcgi_send_timeout 3600;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 3600;
        fastcgi_buffers 8 256k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 256k;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 3600;

############
        client_max_body_size 1024M;
        client_body_buffer_size 128k;
        server_names_hash_max_size 1024;

        client_body_timeout 300;
        client_header_timeout 300;
    keepalive_timeout 600;
        keepalive_requests 100000;
        send_timeout 60;
        server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;

        gzip on;
        gzip_comp_level 6;
        gzip_http_version 1.0;
        gzip_proxied any;
        gzip_min_length 1100;
        gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        gzip_types any;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/octet-stream application/json application/x-javascript application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript text/x-javascript font/ttf application/font-woff font/opentype application/vnd.ms-fontobject image/svg+xml;

        gzip_disable “msie6”;
        gzip_vary on;

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

php-fpm configure file

```
[domain.com.com]
listen = /var/run/php/domain.com-fpm.sock
listen.allowed_clients = 127.0.0.1

listen.owner = nginx
listen.group = nginx

user = domain_live
group = domain_live

; Choose how the process manager will control the number of child processes.
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 150
pm.start_servers = 60
pm.min_spare_servers = 50
pm.max_spare_servers = 90
pm.max_requests = 500

pm.status_path = /status

slowlog = /var/www/www.domain.com.com/logs/php-fpm-www-slow.log
rlimit_core = unlimited
php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/www/www.domain.com.com/logs/php-fpm-www-error.log
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on

; Set session path to a directory owned by process user
php_value[session.save_handler] = files
php_value[session.save_path]     = /var/www/www.domain.com.com/application/var/session
php_value[soap.wsdl_cache_dir]  = /var/lib/php/wsdlcache
```

Getting below error logs

php-fpm error logs

```
WARNING: [pool domain.com] child 4314 exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV - core dumped) after 4556.304032 seconds from start
NOTICE: [pool domain.com] child 6422 started
```

nginx error logs

```
2018/05/18 13:28:02 [error] 4247#4247: *1460 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 1.2.3.4, server: www.domain.com, request: "GET /checkout/cart/ HTTP/2.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/domain.com-fpm.sock:", host: "www.domain.com.com", referrer: "https://www.domain.com.com/customer/account/login/"
```

Please help to resolve this issue. As i'm already tried multiple ways to resolve issue but didn't get the success.